# How to do a "SELECT ... IN (SELECT ...)" using Esqueleto?

Tags: haskell, persistent, servant, esqueleto

Considering the following two models and a `GET /articles/:slug/comments` request, I want to retrieve the comments that belong to an article, based on its `slug`.

```
Article json sql=articles
    slug        Slug
    title       Text
    description Text
    body        Text
    createdAt   UTCTime default=now()
    updatedAt   UTCTime Maybe default=NULL
    userId      UserId
    UniqueSlug  slug

Comment json sql=comments
    body      Text
    createdAt UTCTime default=now()
    updatedAt UTCTime Maybe default=NULL
    articleId ArticleId
    userId    UserId
```

Using persistence's `rawSql`, we can accomplish this as follows

```
getCommentsForArticle :: Slug -> App (Cmts [Entity Comment])
getCommentsForArticle slug = do
    comments <- runDb $ rawSql stm [toPersistValue slug]
    return (Cmts comments)
        where stm = "SELECT ?? FROM comments \
                    \WHERE article_id IN (\
                        \SELECT id FROM articles WHERE slug = ?)"
```

However, given that I want to maintain type safety between Haskell and SQL, I want to rewrite this using `esqueleto`. This is the part I am struggling with. By reading the docs, [sub_select](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-2.5.2/docs/Database-Esqueleto.html#v:sub_select) seems to be the tool for the job. Here's what I have:

```
getCommentsForArticle :: Slug -> App (Cmts [Comment])
getCommentsForArticle slug = do
    comments <- E.select $
        E.from $ \cmts -> do
            let subQuery =
                    E.from $ \arts -> do
                        E.where_ $ arts ^. ArticleSlug ==. E.val slug
                        return (arts ^. ArticleId)
            E.where_ $ cmts ^. CommentArticleId ==. E.sub_select subQuery
            return cmts
    return $ Cmts comments
```

I also noticed the [in_ operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-2.5.2/docs/Database-Esqueleto.html#v:in_), but I can't figure out how to use it nor if it is more appropriate than [sub_select](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-2.5.2/docs/Database-Esqueleto.html#v:sub_select).

What am I missing? Is the syntax correct? Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but `SELECT * ...` is a bad style :). And why not just use SQLite or any other SQL DBs? They are all well typed ;)

Comment: @Igor By bad style you mean not selecting only what is required? As per your second question, I have edited the question to specify I am using `persistent` with `postgresql`.

Comment: Yeah. Why not just use SQL when you need SQL?

Comment: Sorry @Igor, I keep not understanding what you mean by that. Are you suggesting to use just raw SQL for this instead of using Esqueleto?

Comment: Yep, nice and simple :)

Comment: Just compare you SQL example and your haskell code. This is weird :) And btw, shouldn't the compiler tell you about syntax?

Comment: @Igor Esqueleto aims to maintain type safety between Haskell and SQL. If you use plain SQL the compiler can not and will not check types are being marshalled correctly between the two worlds.

Comment: @Igor, what @chi said is the reason why I want to switch to `esqueleto`.

Comment: @chi I added some clarifications to my initial question.

Comment: I can't answer since I have only a very basic experience with Esqueleto, but what's wrong with your code? Does it compile? Does it generate the wrong result?

Comment: Anyway, from a quick look at the docs: `sub_select` only returns *one* value, so it looks as the wrong tool. I'd try `in_` and `subList_select` to match the SQL closely.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want something like this

```
getCommentsForArticle slug = do
  c <- select $ from $ \cmts -> do
         let a = subList_select $ from $ \arts -> do
                 where_ $ arts ^. ArticleSlug ==. val slug
                 return $ arts ^. ArticleId
         where_ $ cmts ^. CommentArticleId `in_` a
         return cmts
  return $ Cmts c
```

Comment: Needs to have a `$` in `subList_select from`, e.g. `subList_select $ from`, will fail otherwise. Please fix